# java Junit4 and JUnit5 not picking JUnit5 tests

Tags: java, junit4, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a work environment including bom I dont manage and **JUnit5 tests are not picked up** unless I import my `@Test` annotation for test methods from `import org.junit.Test;` if I import them from `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` they are not picked up by maven surefire plugin.
I read in many parts and tested in a smaller project and its working and pickedup, I don't know what to include into this post so you have enough information to see where is the issue.
Also if anybody can explain what is under the hood for the imports I read are needed for both JUnit 4 and 5 to work with surefire namely

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--JUnit Jupiter Engine to depend on the JUnit4 engine and JUnit 4 API  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

with versions

```
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.1.0</junit-jupiter.version>
```

I'd appreciate that.

Note that

- my tests are all under src/test/java/.....java
- methods are public
- methods start with test
- classes end with Test

Comment: can you try `mvn dependency:tree` on the problematic project and other small and working ones, then compare the junit related dependencies?

Comment: does the maven version impact that?

Comment: i have no idea. the dependencies may be recursively and implicitly used.

Comment: figured out with a simple project and the more complex I have its a dependency issue, maven can be excluded

Answer (score 0):

Found that this dependency was conflicting, removing it solved my issue

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

also updated spring-boot-dependencies version to `2.6.6`, had issues with `2.3.3.RELEASE`